# google analytics serverside tracking and visiter location

Tags: php, google-analytics

so I'm using the ga.php script you can download from google analytics.

I modified it to not show an image and just do the request because I use it to track an xml file... but it doesn't track any information from utmip.... like location, provider...

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=4.4sh&utmn=1742714795&utmhn=xxxx&utmr=xxxx&utmp=xxxxx&utmac=MO-2xx34486-1&utmcc=__utma%3D999.999.999.999.999.1%3B&utmvid=0x518fcf398ef90b70&utmip=84.192.210.000
```

this is how my request url looks like... as you can see i'm passing the ip to the utmip paramater...

any idea what's causing this?

Comment: I suppose this is probably due to the fact that the request doesnt come from the user machine but from your server. Where did you hear about utmip? I think this parameter is not used anymore. Now it uses the IP from the HTTP request.

Comment: it's working now, haven't checked back on this topic for a while sorry... but for it to work I had to remove the last bit of the ip from utmip

Comment: did you know that you can actually answer your own question ? check FAQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's working now, haven't checked back on this topic for a while sorry... but for it to work I had to remove the last bit of the ip from utmip xx.xx.xx.00 for example....

Comment: A note: the ip is not displayed correctly on realtime dashboard